# How to fill NaN with nearest non NaN value in 2 dimensions

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to fill NaNs in a 2-dimensional xarray (lat, lon) with their nearest value.

I have the following example code in which a land-sea-mask is applied. I would then like to fill the ocean points with their respective nearest land point value.

I know bfill and ffill do something along those lines but not exactly what I am looking for.

Ideally, all ocean points should be filled at the end.

Any ideas?

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import regionmask

def mask_ocean(arr, maskValue=np.nan):
    land = regionmask.defined_regions.natural_earth.land_110.mask(arr)
    masked = xr.where(land==0, arr, maskValue)

    return masked

# Create sample data
lon = np.arange(129.4, 153.75+0.05, 0.25)
lat = np.arange(-43.75, -10.1+0.05, 0.25)
data = 10 * np.random.rand(len(lat), len(lon))
ds   = xr.Dataset({"DC": (["lat", "lon"], data)}, coords={"lon": lon,"lat": lat})

#< Mask ocean
ds = mask_ocean(ds)


#< Plotting
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()}) # Use PlateCarree projection
ds['DC'].plot(ax=axes, cmap='Spectral_r', add_colorbar=True, extend='both')
axes.coastlines() # Add coastlines
plt.show()
```

Comment: What about [interpolate_na](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.interpolate_na.html#xarray-dataarray-interpolate-na) with `method='nearest'`?

Comment: Hi Val, thank you for your comment. I tried interpolate_na but the issue is that it only works for NaNs in between defined values (e.g. 1,2,nan,4,5,... but not nan,2,3,...). Also, interpolate_na only works in one dimension (e.g. lat). It could be run twice (once for lat once for lon), but then the result is not nearest neighbour.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue that I've faced several times, xarray does not
have a proper method to handle this easily.

One possible quick solution is to use CDO

```
cdo setmisstonn inFile.nc outFile.nc
```

that is basically what you want. You can also have a python
interface to cdo ([py-cdo](https://pypi.org/project/cdo/))

```
outds = cdo.setmisstonn(input=ds,returnXDataset=True)
```